# Header title in springer template too long

Tags: header-footer, titles, springer

I'm preparing a paper for submission through the Springer template. The template's title code is the following:

```
\title[Article Title]{Article Title}
```

However, the main title is too long to be used as a header title, and it shows up like this

[image]

Any suggestions??

Comment: `\title[Article Title]{Article \\ Title}`? If you are preparing a manuscript for submission then ask Springer about what to do though, email them as you shouldn't mess with their templates without their advice especially for submission

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: @Andreas Sorry for the late response. We just used a shorter title for the corresponding part afterall

Comment: Thanks for the update, I really hoped for a better solution.